Can I use oil+gas in a mower?
I have a new chainsaw and an old lawnmower, both gas powered.  I need to use a 50:1 mix of gas and oil in the chainsaw.  If I mix this is my gas can and don't use it all, can I use it in the mower as well?  Or will it cause issues?
Edit: mower is a TORO Recycler; engine is made by Kohler and says 149cc

What motor is on the lawn mower? Most mowers have 4 stroke engines, and gas with oil will lead to issues with the engine.

@vidarlo added more info in edit just now
